# using ng-class with angular and kendo-grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Angular directives for KendoUI in my current application. I have a case when i need to use `ng-class` based some field value. i have tried below code but its not working

```
 $scope.getClass = function (b) {
        console.log(b);
    }
$scope.columns = [
        { "field": "Name", "title": "Name" },
        { "field": "StudentId", "title": "Id" },
        { "field": "Address", "title": "Address", template: "<div ng-class='getclass(#:Address#)'>#:Address#</div>" }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

All depends on what is your getclass() method returning, the expression must evaluate to true for one of the listed css classes eg. following will add red onto a `<p>` tag , (you can't return only string name of the class):

```
<p ng-class=" {red : true}" >Using String Syntax</p>
```

OR

```
<span class="base-class" ng-class="myVar='red'">Sample Text</span>
```

Alternatively you need to use `ng-model` to swap in between the classes you listed in the `ng-class` attribute:

```
<p ng-class="style">Using String Syntax</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="style" placeholder="Type: bold strike red">
```

OR `ng-click` to set the variable representing the class.

```
 <input id="clearbtn" type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myVar=''">
 <br>
 <span class="base-class" ng-class="myVar='my-class'">Sample Text</span>
```

Look into the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

This is how you pass the kendo template variable into the scope method ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/UpkTqqrhyd6FF5uwqVyM)):

```
   $scope.columns = [
                  { "field":"name", "title": "name",  template: '<div ng-class="getClass(\'#:name#\')">#:name#</div>'  },
    ];
```

Comment: i know how to use `data-ng-class` my concern is how to bind it with kendo data item. as kendo using `#:PropertyName#` format.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood, I have extended my answer have a look hope it will work for you.

Comment: @RaviMittal how is it looking, does it work for you ?

Comment: nope. Its not working. but if i pass without single quotes then its working for numeric values not for string

Comment: interesting how come its working in the plunker example I have send you, what are you doing differently ?

Comment: Make sure you start with single quotes eg.: `template: '<div ng-class="getClass(\'#:name#\')">#:name#</div>'`